# Multiple Full Screen Backgrounds on the same page with hashes - CSS or maybe Jquery

Tags: background-image, fullscreen

I made a website that has a jquery slider with left and right arrows that move to the next slide (webpage).  All of the content is contained in one webpage and uses hashes. 
http://www.ilandeistudio.com

It needed to have different full screen backgrounds for each page (hash) so I used a CSS technique that puts full screen backgrounds in DIVs which I found here (CSS Technique 1)
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

This works but the height of the image is running off the bottom of the screen and therefore adding vertical scrollbars and you can't see the whole background image.  I don't mind distorting the backgrounds a little (they are all w1024px x h682px) I just want the whole image in the viewable area.

I haven't been able to get it to work with CSS, let me know if someone has a suggestion otherwise maybe someone could recommend a jquery solution; but I don't know how to make most of those jquery examples work inside the DIVs for the multiple hashes.

Here is the CSS I am using now:

```
        img.bg {
        /* Set rules to fill background */
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 1024px;

        /* Set up proportionate scaling */
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;

        /* Set up positioning */
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
        img.bg {
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -512px; }
    }
```

And here are examples of two of the slides

```
               <div id="home" class="slide">
                <img src="images/bg_home1.jpg" class="bg">
          <div class="outer-wrapper">
                  <div class="inner-wrapper">
                        <div class="header">
                            <a href="#home" class="special-anchor"></a>

                            <div class="nav">
                                <a href="#" class="prev-button special-anchor" title="Previous">Previous</a>
                                <span class="rightnav"><a href="#" class="next-button special-anchor" title="Next">Next</a></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                                test content
                        </div>
                        <!--Content ends-->
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>

          <div id="about" class="slide">
                <img src="images/bg_about1.jpg" class="bg">
                <div class="outer-wrapper">
                  <div class="inner-wrapper">
                        <!--Header starts-->
                        <div class="header">
                            <a href="#about" class="special-anchor"></a>
                            <!--Navigation starts-->
                            <div class="nav">
                                <a href="#" class="prev-button special-anchor" title="Previous">Previous</a>
                                <span class="rightnav"><a href="#" class="next-button special-anchor" title="Next">Next</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <!--Navigation ends-->
                        </div>
                        <!--Content starts-->
                        <div class="content">
                        test content 02
                        </div>
                        <!--Content ends-->
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code itself looks correct. One thing that you didn't include but I would make sure of is that the **header and navigation you have listed are positioned absolutely** on the page rather than floating left and using margins to position things. That will add space to the 100% of the page.

So the image itself is expanding to the height of the page and the heights of header and navigation are being added on top of that. Most likely that is the problem if you seem to scrolling the height of those objects.